# Is deck flooring an OK alternative to a concrete slab for a sport court?

Tags: deck, foundation

I'm thinking of building a sports court for mostly inline hockey. Similar to this one.
[image]

I have a land with grass and was wondering if there is another way to create a base, foundation under the floor tiles beside pouring concrete.

And I realized that one of the options could be to make a raised deck. Something like this:
[image]

Ideally like this but this below look little unprofessional[image]:

Are there any directions on how to DIY the deck and is it even feasible or what are the pros and cons of using deck floor for a sports court? I checked this [site](http://www.diybackyardsports.com/is-concrete-required.html) and they don't mention this option. However, they mention Compacted Base but that's not recommended for larger courts. Why is this type of flooring for sports court not more discussed?

Comment: You're asking several very broad questions here. Please narrow the focus of your post and ask just one.

Comment: @isherwood, the main question is in the title. The rest is optional.

Comment: @Grasper You answered the title question yourself

Comment: @mmathis, ok I changed my post a little.

Comment: For inline use I think decking may be problematic. Even tightly spaced there will be ridges if the boards start cupping that could be worse.

Comment: @EdBeal, I'm planning to put tiles for hockey on top of the boards.

Comment: @Grasper, Cupping and warping of boards will eventually lead to gaps or unevenness in your tiles.  Any natural wood product will warp to some degree over time.  I'm not sure how much that matters with skates and the tile floor.

Comment: With something on top I would think it would be ok

Comment: I would think that the flooring wouldn't be ridged enough, causing the tiles to "pop" loose. After building a ridged deck, one that won't flex too much, you could be looking at close to the same cost as pouring concrete. Look into the cost of both.